# installing @angular/pwa results in error: A dynamic import callback was not specified

Tags: angular, angular-pwa

Installing `@angular/pwa` gives error:

```
$ ng add @angular/pwa --project angular-tic-tac-toe
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/pwa@15.2.9.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/pwa@15.2.9 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
A dynamic import callback was not specified.
```

Running it for the second time gives `Segmentation fault` error.

Why could it happen? This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "angular-tic-tac-toe",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "11.0.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "^11.0.0",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "~15.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```